# What is the best way to show the Visualforce PDF page in 3 different languages?

Tags: visualforce, customlabel, translation, translation-workbench, label

We have a site in one language and we need to show 3 different versions of the site (we have translations) in another 2 languages.
It would be better to create 3 different visualforce sites (each for different language) or to use labels?
Text in pdf is really big

Answer (score 0):

According to Salesforce, you can use **language** attribute in your Visualforce page in order to establish what the page language's going to be.
[Documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

So, using Custom Labels + Translation Workbench + Visualforce Page with "language" should be enough.